# Google maps drawing path works till some point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array with latlang values, and i want to draw a path which follows this values. This is what i did but it only draws till some point. When i console.log the 'result', expect the drawn objects, it prints

`Uncaught Error: Error in property <routes>: (Cannot read property 'routes' of null)`

```
function renderDirections(result) {

  var directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionDisplay.setDirections(result);
  directionDisplay.setOptions({suppressMarkers: true});
}

for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(array[i].lat, array[i].lng),
                    map: map                                 
                    });

                    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    directionsService.route({
                    origin:  new google.maps.LatLng(array[i].lat, array[i].lng),
                    destination:  new google.maps.LatLng(array[i+1].lat, array[i+1].lng),
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    },
                    function(result){
                      renderDirections(result);
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "status" of the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService).  The DirectionsService is subject to a quota and rate limits.

```
                directionsService.route({
                  origin:  new google.maps.LatLng(array[i].lat, array[i].lng),
                  destination:  new google.maps.LatLng(array[i+1].lat, array[i+1].lng),
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                },
                function(result, status){
                  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                    renderDirections(result);
                  else alert ("Directions request failed:"+status);
                });
```

The problem with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined" is due to your logic.  array[i+1] does not exist when you get to your last directions request.  Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i < array.length-1; i++){
```

[example using function closure](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_directions_multipleA.html)

[This example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html) of stringing multiple requests together may help you as well.

Comment: now it didn't draw any paths and gave "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined" error with the alert you wanted me to write. but it gives an empty status it just prints "Directions request failed:".

Comment: Sounds like you did more than just add the status check.  There was a typo in my suggested check, but it doesn't explain the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: i just added the two extra lines you wrote. when i comment them it still draws as i asked in my question...

Comment: "Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined" is actually irrelevant, it prints it because it finishes the loop at that point, so it isnt the problem. after adding the status check it stopped to render paths and only alerts "Directions request failed:" without a status

Comment: Missed that. Your "i" is past the end of the array.  This is a duplicate question, you can use function closure to retain the value of the index to the array for calls to the directions service.  However, once you fix that you will get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT (at least I do).

Comment: how do i use the function closure in my example?

Comment: See my updated answer.  You probably will have to change your architecture. Send a request when you receive the result of the previous request, add the ability to delay when you get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT responses.